# How to extract the percentage from the last row using grep?

Tags: bash, wget

I'm trying to download a file using `wget` and want to store the progress in a log file.

`wget http://unfccc.int/resource/docs/convkp/kpeng.pdf -O amit.pdf 2> amit.log`

This is what wget returns:

```
Connecting to unfccc.int (unfccc.int)|62.225.2.55|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 76721 (75K) [application/pdf]
Saving to: `amit.pdf'

 0K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 66% 2.29M 0s
50K .......... .......... ....                            100% 9.41M=0.02s

2013-08-28 12:24:32 (3.06 MB/s) - `amit.pdf' saved [76721/76721]
```

I want to get the percentage value from the last row using grep. This is what i've used along with the above command which does not work:

```
| grep "(\d+(\.\d+)?(?=%)" amit.log
```

Is it possible only using grep and without using sed and awk?

Comment: What do you exactly want to grep? What do you mean by "the percentage value from the last row"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your pattern contains unmatched `(`.
2. You need to tell `grep` that you're using PCRE.
3. Since you're redirecting `STDERR` to a file, using a pipe to `grep` wouldn't make much sense.  Instead, redirect `STDERR` to `STDOUT` and then pipe the output.

Try:

```
grep -oP "(\d+(\.\d+)?(?=%))"
```

If you want to use a pipe, say:

```
wget http://unfccc.int/resource/docs/convkp/kpeng.pdf -O amit.pdf 2>&1 | grep -oP "(\d+(\.\d+)?(?=%))"
```

EDIT: If `stderr` needs to be logged to a file, say:

```
wget http://unfccc.int/resource/docs/convkp/kpeng.pdf -O amit.pdf 2>&1 | tee amit.log | grep -oP "(\d+(\.\d+)?(?=%))"
```

Comment: Thanks @devnull The command works but not as expected. The amit.log file becomes empty until the amit.pdf is fully downloaded. I want to update the file on every progress.

This is what I did:
`wget http://unfccc.int/resource/docs/convkp/kpeng.pdf -O amit.pdf 2>&1 | grep -oP "(\d+(\.\d+)?(?=%))" >> amit.log`

Comment: You're doing it wrong.  Pipe to `tee logfile` and then grep.  See edit above.

Comment: Thats perfect with a little change. I want to log the grep output in a file.

Comment: redirect it to a file in that case.  e.g. add `> percent.log` at the end of the command.

Comment: percentage.log does not update until the download is finished.

Comment: Ah! It should have been `| tee percent.log` instead.

Comment: not working. 

`wget http://static.clipcanvas.com/sample/clipcanvas_14348_DVCPRO_720p25.mov -O 1.mov 2>&1 | tee amit.log | grep -oP "(\d+(\.\d+)?(?=%))" | tee percentage.log`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36435/discussion-between-devnull-and-codef0rmer)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to extract the last percentage from the command output to be able to spot eventual failures.

As [@devnull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2235132/devnull) commented, the `wget` verbose output is wrote on the standard error, so we have to redirect it to the standard output to be able to pipe it to grep.

It is possible to keep the `grep` matching pattern only by using the `-o` option. This will print all the percentages without the undesired content.

Then you can isolate the last line with `tail`.

Finally, log it into a file.

---

```
wget http://unfccc.int/resource/docs/convkp/kpeng.pdf -O amit.pdf 2>&1 | grep -o '[0-9]\+%' | tail -1 > amit.log
```

Comment: The `wget` *log* that contains the *percentages* is sent to `STDERR` so the pipe to `grep` wouldn't have any effect here.

Comment: Hate to say that, but it's still broken.

Comment: Specifying character class in the form `\d` wouldn't work by default.

Comment: Hum I haven't this issue on OSX, I fixed it to me more portable.

Comment: Thanks @abeaumet The command works but not as expected. The amit.log  file becomes empty until the amit.pdf is fully downloaded. I want to update the file on every progress.